# How to highlight text on web pages using a keyboard

Tags: accessibility, nvda

I need to take screenshots of a web page. I want to highlight certain areas of the page before taking the screenshot. I am visually impaired, so using the mouse is out of the question.
I generally use shift and the arrow keys to select text. While this works on web pages, the text is selected, but not highlighted. IE I know it is selected, but someone who will look at the screenshot won't be able to see it.

Q: is there a way of highlighting text on a web page using the keyboard?
I am using Windows 11 with NVDA as my screen reader.

Comment: Most browsers support "Caret Browsing" (F7).  Firefox, Chrome, IE, and Edge all have the same shortcut key.  Not sure about Safari. You can then move through a webpage using the arrow keys as if it were a document then hold shift while selecting text. A sighted user can see the selected text as if done with a mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be possible with Google Chrome if the accessibility option "Navigate pages with a text cursor" is enabled—also known as "caret browsing". Here is a Google Chrome help article about it: ["Use a text cursor to navigate & select text"](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10129654?hl=en).

The article states that this setting can be toggled by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>, or by opening the "Customize and control Google Chrome" menu, opening "Settings", navigating to the "Advanced" tab, then selecting "Accessibility".

This mode allows you to use the arrow keys to move the text cursor around the page, similar to if you were editing a block of text. Text can be visually highlighted by navigating to the start of the text you want to highlight, holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, and then arrowing to the end of the text.

I'm not sure how well this will work in conjunction with NVDA though.